# Set line spacing of footer in word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2013

I want to set line spacing of footer of word document to exactly 12 pt.

I used this code

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 12
```

But it doensn't work. I'm using word 2013.

Comment: Does it work if you select the paragraph and run the code again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by my self.

This will do the job.

```
With Selection.ParagraphFormat
    .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly
    .LineSpacing = 12
End With
```